Noise Voltage from Sinusoidal Flux Density Derivation
From page 52 of Electromagnetic Compatibility Engineering by Henry Ott; How was the imaginary and omega component in eq. 2-12 derived from eq. 2-11? And how did the negative sign disappear?



The reference in the book should explain it.

@VoltageSpike, it didn't really explain it

No explanation given - that's possible, because EMC engineering books are not intended to be books for the elementary phasor calculus used in AC circuits. Your book assumes the reader knows the basics of the ordinary phasor calculus including what's the validity range of the phasor calculus and how to present with complex number valued phasors

sinusoidal voltages and currents
operation of capacitors, inductors, coupled inductors and resistors
Kirchoff's circuit laws

Your integral formula (2-11) says that a non-loaded wire loop catches voltage which is the the growth rate of the total magnetic flux through the loop. It's essentially Faraday's induction law in vector field math format. The minus is a consequence of the concepts of positive sides and directions of space curve loops and surfaces bounded by the loops.
In exactly performed rigorous vector field calculations one gets the right polarity to the caught voltage when he also takes the minus sign into the account. Measuring the caught RMS or peak voltage induced by a sinusoidally varying magnetic field with a multimeter gives no difference whether a person happens to think the minus sign or not.
The second formula (2-12) presents the complex phasor of the AC voltage caught by unloaded planar loop. The minus sign has not magically vanished. It's left out as an useless factor  useless because the positive loop direction, the positive side of by the loop bounded surface and the actual direction of the flux density at t=0 are not defined. The formula gives for engineering purposes the right complex phasor of the induced voltage when the resistors are infinite.
The factor jw comes from the math basics of the phasor calculus. Sinusoidally varying magnetic flux through the loop induces still the same voltage as shown in (2-11), but d(sin(wt))/dt = w(cos(wt)). Cosine of (wt) has pi/2 radians i.e.90 degrees phase lead when compared to sin(wt). It's still sinusoidal, but the peak or RMS value is multiplied by w. In phasor calculus math foundations there's also shown that 90 degrees of phase lead means for the complex phasor the same as being multiplied by the imaginary unit j.
The cosine in (2-12) takes into the account the possibility that the flux is not perpendicular with the loop plane.It has nothing to do with the derivative of sin(wt).
Brush up your basic engineering level AC circuit analysis skills to become able to follow books which apply the math of analysis. Then you'll see for example, that loading the loop causes the voltage to drop due the less than 100% magnetic coupling between the loop and the source circuit of the disturbing magnetic field.

It's basically from this, the cos is from the the angle between the direction of flux and the area encompassed (since there is only one coil N is )
The other component comes from the \$ \frac{d}{dt} \$:
usually without going into a lot of math you can consider AC frequencies as this:
\$ \frac{d}{dt} \leftrightarrow j\omega \leftrightarrow  s\$
because you can't create voltage in a coil without induction and a changing magnetic field the \$ \frac{d}{dt} \$  means the field in changing

Source: https://sdsu-physics.org/physics180/physics196/Topics/faradaysLaw.html
